# What is impedance 'masking' and how it is related to impedance 'matching'?

Tags: power-electronics, impedance-matching

While reading ECSS-E-ST-20C Standard, I have encountered with a concept named 'impedance mask'. However, I could not find any detailed definition or explanation related to it.

In the corresponding article, it is said that :

"At the point of regulation, the impedance mask of a fully regulated bus, operating with one source shall be below the impedance mask shown in Figure 5‐1."

[image]

I would like to know what impedance masking is and how it is related to -if so- impedance matching.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think it's talking about a DC power distribution bus and basically it's saying that the source of the regulated voltage on that bus must have a very low output impedance. If it didn't have a low output impedance it wouldn't regulate very well.

The term "mask" just refers to the allowable "top-limit" of impedance that is acceptable and, as far as I can tell has no bearing on such concepts as impedance matching.

So, take the example of a 5V bus capable of putting out 100 watts. At low frequencies (0.01 Hz or less) the output impedance can be calculated from the graph as: -

0.002 x voltage\$^2\$ / power = 0.4 milli ohms

---

OK I found ECSS-E-ST-20C and it says (regarding this test): -

> NOTE 2 Rationale for the impedance mask: It translates requirement
>   5.7.2i.1 of 1 % voltage change for 50 % load change in a domain of regulation up to 10 kHz bandwidth. In DC the integrator in the control
>   loop is designed to ensure no static error, in higher frequency,
>   between 10 kHz and 100 kHz it is likely that the inductance effect of
>   the components and connections are seen and the impedance rise not
>   always making feasible to respect the ideal impedance mask.

This proves to me it is about power sources feeding a power bus.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Andyaka. Here we are talking about ripple frequency on the bus, right? Also, I cannot say that I clearly understand why it wouldn't regulate well if I didn't keep the output impedance of the source low.

Comment: No, ripple frequency is something else. If a battery has a zero output impedance then any change of load will produce ZERO effect on the battery voltage. If on the other hand it has an output impedance of 1 ohm then clearly it cannot keep pure regulation when load current is changing.

Answer (score 5):

It means the impedance needs to be below the line.

If you measure the impedance over frequency with a network analyzer, you get a single trace. Placing the mask over the trace would hide it completely for a conforming bus.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @SimonRichter. What do you mean by 'placing the mask' exactly?

Comment: You are ignoring any measurement points below the given line, so these are "masked out", as if a piece of cardboard was placed over the display. Any points not hidden are violations of the specification.